# Problems with LTXtable und endfloat / processdelayedfloats

Tags: tables, floats, ltxtable

I need to place all my tables and figures at the end of my document. With the `enfloat` package, I managed to do so with most of my tables.
However, I have a very long table that only works for me if I include it via the `ltxtable` package. 
The problem is that my LTXtable wont float to the end of my document like all the other tables.
I thought about defining a new float enviornment but did not know how.

I am thankful for any suggestions!

I place a minimal example below (I hope that suits the purpose):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,longtable, afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % use utf8 for all files
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} %footnotes for figures
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat} % place figures at the end 
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}
\caption{table 2}
bla bla
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \LTXtable{\linewidth}{table 2}
    \end{spacing}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\section{Print all tables here}

\processdelayedfloats
\makeatletter
\efloat@restorefloats
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

This is my LTXtable saved in the file "table 2":

```
\begin{longtable}[t!hbp]{x c c}}
    \caption{Table 2}\label{Tab: 2} \\ \toprule
    A very very long table
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,longtable, afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % use utf8 for all files
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} %footnotes for figures
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat} % place figures at the end
\newenvironment{mylongtable}{}{}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{mylongtable}{table}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}
\caption{table 2}
bla bla
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{mylongtable}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{spacing}{1}
    blblblblb    % \LTXtable{\linewidth}{table 2}
    \end{spacing}
\end{landscape}
\end{mylongtable}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\section{Print all tables here}

\processdelayedfloats
\makeatletter
\efloat@restorefloats
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I really need to fit an LTXtable, i.e. I need to combine a longtable and tabularx.

Comment: I only removed the \LTXtable for the test, Doesn't it work if you reenable it?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not try that. Yes, it works! Thank you so much!